# Error at const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am a React Native beginner and getting the error which I don't understand why.  Could someone point it out?

```
import { TextInput, View } from "react-native";
import React, {useState} from react; 


class NumberField extends React.Component{
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{textLabel}</Text>
                <TextInput 
                    value={data}
                    onChangeText={(value) => setData(value)}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

The error is at the = sign of the useState line.  It says "; expected".

Not sure what else to try.  There are many samples instruct to do that way.

Comment: That's simply not how classes work in JS, not a React problem. At the React level you're mixing up class- and function-based components.

Comment: Oh.  I was just following the example here, mid page:
https://devbrite.io/react-native-custom-components

Comment: Dev-not-so-brite

Answer (score 1):

React have two ways to define components:

- The old way: Class Components
- Function Components with Hooks.

Hooks in React means the function that starts with `use` prefix such as `useState`. You can use Hooks only in Function Components.

To use state in Class Components you could use `this.state`

```
class NumberField extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Initializing state
    this.state = {value: ""}
  }

    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{textLabel}</Text>
                <TextInput 
                    value={data}
                    onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({value})}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Hooks such as `useState` can't be used in Class Components.

The tutorial you're following is not a good place to learn since it's not accurate. Here are some resources to learn the modern React correctly:

- React Documentation: https://react.dev
- React Native Documentation: https://reactnative.dev/

Comment: Yes I found the hard way.  It worked for functional component but not class component.  I coded it different than yours but I will mark yours as answer.
I went to react native site but the documents cover very basic stuffs.  Not enough coverage to be able to develop an app.
It is interesting that you said the old way is the class way.  I thought the functional component is more of a "quick" way. lol

Comment: A couple minor corrections:
this.state = "" should be this.state = { value: ""} 
this.setState(value) should be this.setState({value:value})
Otherwise it gives error about setState() takes object

Comment: @PhucLy thanks for the correction. tbh, I never wrote a class component.